# PortQry Runtime Error

Tags: windows, runtime-error, port, portqry

Operating System: Windows 7
Application: portqry/portqry UI

Error:
Portqry Runtime error #3 The 'hp' variable is undefined.

I've searched Google for a couple days and can't find why portqry is giving me this error. When I press ignore everything seems to work fine but port 53 is also timing out when running portqry (separate issue). Does anyhow know how to solve this runtime error?

Answer (score 0):

This issue had me going for a couple days but the one thing I never thought off was to disable the firewall. Not one of my top choices to do when it comes to security but the move is ok when it's on an intranet; no connection to the internet. This solved the port 53 timeout error & the runtime error.